# Cannot set htmlAttribute parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm adding in the object htmlAttributes parameter and getting an error :

> "Error    41  Invalid anonymous type
>   member declarator. Anonymous type
>   members must be declared with a member
>   assignment, simple name or member
>   access"

```
Response.Write(Html.CheckBox("chkStatus", item.Value) + " " + item.Text + "<br />");
Response.Write(Html.CheckBox("chkStatus", item.Value,new {checked=true}) + " " + item.Text + "<br />");
```

I get the error when i try to add the "new {checked=true} part.

Cannot find an example of setting parameter in c# code online, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **checked** is a keyword. Try putting an @ in front:

```
new { @checked = true }
```

Comment: It builds ok with :Response.Write("&nbsp&nbsp" + Html.CheckBox("chkStatus_" + item.Value, item.Value, new { @checked = "true" }) + " " + item.Text + "<br />");

Comment: but I get error runtime of : CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Lms.Web.Models.FormViewModels.SiteFormViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'CheckBox' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.CheckBox(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, bool, object)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Its still not happy with the syntax for the parameter, i'm missing something, cannot figure it

Comment: What is the type of item.Value? - it should be bool.

Comment: AHH thanks - an oversight on my part, I never even needed the HTML attribute parameter, i just set a true or false for 2nd param and no 3rd oaram, cheers